# Create and Display a Div using JQuery without distorting other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a div and show a timeout message in there. But it actually distorts other parts of Page. For eg see below. Session Timed out is the div with the message.
[image]

Now I don't want this to happen. PFB the JQuery code I am using to create this Div

```
function ShowSessionTimeOutDiv() {
        var styler = document.createElement("div");
        styler.setAttribute("style","font-size:15px;width:auto;height:auto;top:50%;left:40%;color:red;");

        styler.innerHTML = "<b><i>Session TimedOut, Please refresh the Page</i></b>";
        document.body.appendChild(styler);

        var currentDiv = $('#GoToRequestControl1_UpdatePanel1').get(0); 
        currentDiv.parentNode.insertBefore(styler,currentDiv) ;
    }
```

Am I missing something here? The Part in which this div is being displayed is coming from Master Page.

Comment: What do you mean _"distorts"_ other elements? Do you mean it shifts their positions around when your newly created div is added? (which is not what 'distort' means)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `position:fixed` styling on it in css, i did that on one of my websites and it didn't distort anything.

Comment: [Example WebPage](https://gyazo.com/6dad2778acd9e7d51c7743dc58a6c6dd) here's an example of what it looks like. Now that i think about it it may not be what you want...

Answer (score 0):

A page has a natural flow of its elements based on the default display rules specified by the W3C.  When you add a div in between other elements it naturally affects the layout of the page; the positions of the other elements.

In order to drop in a new element without it affecting other elements you have to either reserve space for it, or take it out of the normal page flow.

There are a couple of ways to take an element out of the flow — you can `float` it, `float:left` or `float:right`, which is great, for example, to stack blocks on the left (instead of top-down) and let them wrap to new rows as available width changes. Using a flex layout gives you a lot of control also. But in this case of one thing popping up, changing the `position`ing of the new element is the most straightforward and can let you put the block exactly where you want it.

I have a demonstration and full explanation in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/nmvpvfga/2/) showing several examples along the way to getting what you want.

Basically, styling is needed to reposition the timeout message element that you're inserting. Styling is better done with CSS styles, compared to adding a bunch of inline styles. If I put my timeout popup message in a *"messagebox"* I can make a class for it.

```
/* Your styles, plus a couple extra to make the example stand out better */
div.messagebox {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    top: 40%;
    left: 30%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Likewise, style the message itself with a class, instead of using inline styles and the deprecated presentational tags `<b>` and `<i>`.

```
/* I want the message in a messagebox to be bold-italic-red text. */
div.messagebox .message {
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The big difference is that we will change the positioning of the element from the default `static` to instead use *absolute* positioning:

```
/* I don't really recommend a class called "positioned".
   A class should describe the kind of thing the element *is*
   not how it *looks*
*/
div.messagebox.positioned {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 1.5em;
}
/* The container of the positioned element also has to be positioned.
   We position it "relative" but don't move it from its natural position.
*/
section#hasposition {
    position: relative;
}
```

The term "absolute" is tricky to learn ... the element being positioned is given an absolute position *within its container*, in a sense it's positioned relative to its container... but what `position:relative` means is *relative to its own natural position*, so it's easy to get confused at first over whether you want absolute or relative positioning.

Putting it all together, we have some basic HTML that represents major portions of a page — a real page will have far more, but those should be contained within some top-level containers. This shows only those top-level containers.
Then we have some javascript that will add the new element at the appropriate time.  Here I just call the function to add it after a delay created with `setTimeout()`. I'm using full-on jQuery since you're using some in your example, and it makes the javascript more portable and more concise.

```js
function ShowSessionTimeoutStyled() {
    var styler = $('<div>').addClass('messagebox').addClass('positioned');
    styler.html('<span class="message">The Session Timed Out</span>');
    $('#hasposition .above').after(styler);
}
// wait 6 seconds then add the new div
setTimeout(ShowSessionTimeoutStyled, 6000);
```

```css
div.messagebox {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
div.messagebox .message {
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}
div.messagebox.positioned {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 1.5em;
}
section#hasposition {
    position: relative;
}
/* also style some of the basic parts so you can see them better in the demonstration */
section.explanation {
    margin: 1em 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
 .demonstration {
    margin-left: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
.demonstration .above {
    background-color: #fff0f0;
}
.demonstration .middle {
    background-color: #f0fff0;
}
.demonstration .below {
    background-color: #f0f0ff;
}
.demonstration footer {
    background-color: white;
}
p {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
section {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="explanation">
    <p>Here, a div is added dynamically, after the "basic part above", but the added div is <em>positioned</em>. You can see the other content isn't affected.</p>
    <section class="demonstration" id="hasposition">
        <div class="above">Basic part above</div>
        <div class="middle">Middle part</div>
        <div class="below">Part Below</div>
        <footer>This is the page footer</footer>
    </section>
</section>
```

I highly recommend the site [Position Is Everything](http://www.positioniseverything.net/) for articles and tutorials on positioning. Some of its other content is outdated — who needs to make PNGs to do drop-shadows any more? — but the way positioning works hasn't changed.

Comment: I am working on it Stephen...Not sure why someone downvoted me...It might be difficult for me while for some of them its like a piece of cake....:(